# Компиляция из приложения

Tags: delphi

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы exe файл компилировался из самой программы(Уже скомпилированной в Delphi)? Если можно то как? Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 4):

Можно, но Вам нужно тащить с собой компилятор и библиотеки. А это с лицензионной точки зрения может быть не совсем хорошо.
А так в принципе - все просто. Сохраняем файл, а потом запускайте DCC32.EXE имяфайла.pas
Сам DCC32.EXE можно найти в каталоге bin дефли (в некоторый версиях его нет). С своего приложения можно запустить через WinExec или CreateProcess.
С другой стороны, можно написать свой компилятор, но это сложная задача. Или воспользоватся freepascal.